# Inserting hyperlink to PART of a range (in word)

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, office-js

I'm working on a word add-in, and I want to insert a hyperlink to part of a range (the range being the selected text by the user).

I'm aware of the range.hyperlink method but I don't know how to split up the range, and only hyperlink a specific part of it.

For example the range "I have a small boat" - The user selects the whole string, but the hyperlink should only be added to the word "small".

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can search for the range http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154604/how-should-range-expandto-be-used-in-the-word-javascript-api or modify the OOXML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892507/insert-comment-in-word-using-office-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the late replay, but here is the answer. You have a couple of options. The way to think about this problem in general is, how can i get the right Ranges? so that then I can setup the hyperlinks (or do almost any operation of the API, such as inserting or formatting content!). Your options are.

1. **Search**. From within the selection you can do a search for "small", you will get a collection of ranges that matched your criteria. Here is an example of how to do this.

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
 var searchResults = context.document.getSelection().search("small");
 context.load(searchResults);
 return context.sync()
 .then(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
      searchResults.items[i].hyperlink = "http://dev.office.com";

    }
    return context.sync()
  })
})
.catch(function (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
})
```

2. **Split** the selection. You can use the split method to get word by word your selection. Here is a code sample on how to do this:

```js
  Word.run(function (context) {

            var myWords = context.document.getSelection().split([" "],false, true);
            context.load(myWords);
            return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < myWords.items.length; i++) {
                    if(myWords.items[i].text === "small")
                        myWords.items[i].hyperlink = "http://dev.office.com";

                }
                return context.sync()
            })



        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        })
```

Hope you find this useful and happy coding!!

Juan.

Comment: Thank you so much Juan. It seems to be working now. Greatly appreciated.